# How to disable Wordpress top menu link?

Tags: wordpress

How to disable top menu link in Wordpress to avoid redirect to another page on click. I only need to show submenus.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add custom link to menu item (Put # value on link)

1. Log into your WordPress administration panel. Navigate to Appearance, and select Menus:
2. Navigate to Links on the left and type in the URL you want to have for this menu button, add Link Text to specify what the tab will say, and then click Add to Menu:
3. Optionally, if you would like to control whether your menu link opens in a new tab when clicked, check the “Link Target” advanced property from within Screen Options to reveal this setting on individual menu items:
4. Refresh the site and you will see your new custom page and link in the navigation menu.

Answer (score 1):

Give the menu item link a the value `#`.

Then you'll need some Javascript to prevent default link clicking action.

E.g. with jQuery:

```
$('.class').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

// replace class with whatever the selector of the link is. To cover ALL menu items that have sub menus (and have the WP classes), you can use '.menu-item-has-children a'
```